# How to call a function whose prototype is scoped inside another function?

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

to declare a function prototype we declare it outside and on the top which means right before the function definition.

1- I wonder why c++ allows declaring `prototypes scoped` inside the body of other functions' definitions?

2- How to call a function whose prototype being inside another function's body?

here is an example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Bar()
{
    cout << "Bar..." << endl;
    void Baz();
}

int main()
{

    void Foo();
    Foo();
    Bar();
    Baz(); // how to call this function?

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void Foo()
{
    cout << "Foo..." << endl;
}

void Baz()
{
    cout << "Baz..." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function prototype inside one function isn't visible inside another, so the code you've written here won't work. However, there's nothing stopping you from providing another function prototype inside of `main`:

```
int main()
{

    void Foo();
    Foo();
    Bar();

    void Baz();
    Baz();

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

That having been said, it's pretty unusual to write code like this - if you mean to prototype the function, just do so at global scope. It's rare to see function prototypes defined inside of individual functions and is almost always a mistake or extremely poor coding style.

C++ allows this for two reasons:

1. Backwards compatibility. This is legal C code, and historically C++ tried to maintain compatibility with C whenever possible. (There's a lot of legal C code that won't compile in C++, so this isn't a hard-and-fast rule, but it's a good guiding philosophy.)
2. The "Why Not?" principle. Function prototypes are really just declarations of functions. C++ lets you declare all sorts of objects at different points in time. Allowing function declarations like this inside of a function follows as a special case of allowing for declarations, so explicitly disallowing it would require extra verbage in the spec and potentially might hurt someone in a really bizarre case down the line.

Arguably, this was a bad decision, because it leads to C++'s Most Vexing Parse. The following line of code, for example, is interpreted as a function prototype:

```
std::vector<int> x(); // Oops - it's a function prototype!
```

Even worse is something like this:

```
std::istream input;
std::vector<int> x(istream_iterator<int>(input), istream_iterator<int>()); // Oops - it's a function prototype!
```

This was addressed by adding in the new brace initialization syntax:

```
std::vector<int> x{}; // Okay, a vector.
std::vector<int> x{istream_iterator<int>{input}, istream_iterator<int>{}}; // Sure, that's fine too.
```

Comment: yes. I don't want to do that in a real. but I only wonder why C++ allows this although for scoping there's namespaces and OOP

Comment: Functions within functions feels an awful lot like Pascal.  Maybe this was the reason?  Dunno.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan C++ lets you *prototype* functions inside of other functions but not *define* functions inside other functions.

Comment: @templatetypedef: `std::vector<int> x();` you mean with this `instantiate of vector class, calling the default ctor` is seen by the compiler as a function that returns `vector<int>` instead?

Comment: @Lee5 That's actually *not* an instantiation of a vector using the default constructor, even though it looks like one! Instead, it's treated as a prototype of a function called `x` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @templatetypedef: `vector<int> x` doesn't mean creating an object of `vector<int>`? I know writing `vector<int> x()` is calling explicitly the default ctor. while `vector<int> x` ctor implicitly called. `That's actually not an instantiation of a vector using the default constructor` please explain clearly this

Comment: Writing `std::vector<int> x;` creates a vector initialized with the default constructor. Writing `std::vector<int> x();` with parentheses does not even create a vector. Try this out in a compiler with the warning level cranked up to max and see what it says and does.